# Adding Flash animation to an android studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation, flash-cs6

Is it possible to add an animation flash to my android studio project?

Comment: FLash is not supported on Android.  Really it shouldn't be used anywhere-  Adobe no longer supports it, and its been one of the least secure pieces of software for the past 15 years.  There's a reason why browsers ship with it off by support and will most likely not allow it at all soon.

Comment: In short: **NO**.

Comment: Flash is spyware/virus backdoor. The less anyone uses it for anything, the better.

Comment: Did you even google the subject before asking? I bet there are hundreds of write-ups on line that would have more than adequately answered your question.

Comment: You mean that it would be better to use other websites than  stackoverflow ?
why stackoverflow exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long answer short:
As far as I know no.

Why?
Because there are more performant ways you can do this on Android.

You have different other options you can investigate further if you want some nice animations in your app.
One is to make a [Custom View](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) extending either View or ViewGroup where you have all the liberty you want to draw on a Canvas.

Another popular approach nowadays is to use [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html).
You can use a relatively 'simple' vector animation and have it up and running in no time.
You can use this [AndroidIconAnimator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidIconAnimator/) which is an online tool which will help you a lot if you use this approach.

You can check out this [post](https://medium.com/@timrijckaert/play-pause-stop-animated-vector-drawable-88a9df956d20#.kjftb525s) for a 'tutorial' on how to use this tool.

[image]

And last but certainly not least I would recommend taking a look at Facebook's tool for animations [KeyFrames](https://github.com/facebookincubator/Keyframes) I personally haven't used this one, but it looks very promising.
It comes as close to your question as possible.
This tool allows you to export an Adobe After Effects project into a running animation on your phone.
They used it internally for their reactions/emoticons.
[image]

Comment: Thank You Very very Much !!
you are just amazing !

Comment: Hey, if it helped please accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: hi sorry but how can i accept the answer ? im new :p

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
Basically you have a green check mark you can click

Comment: Done ^_^ !!!
thank you again